# Change admin CP default locale

Tags: localization, default

I have 3 locales set up - `en_ca`, `fr_ca`, `en_us`.  `en_us` was selected when installing Craft.  I had to change the default locale to `en_ca` and did so in `general.php` after installation.  I'd like this change in the CP as well.  Currently, entering new entries and the CP site link all still point to `en_us`.

How can I change the default locale?

Comment: Have you checked under "Locales" in Craft Settings? You need to change it here as well.

Comment: @naboovalley I've change the order so that en_ca is first, followed by en_fr and en_us.  However I can't find a 'Set to default' option.

Comment: As Brad Bell pointed out, changing my user's preferred locale solved the issue.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the locale to `en_ca` in the control panel under Settings->Locales.

Comment: I've change the order so that en_ca is first, followed by en_fr and en_us.  However I can't find a 'Set to default' option.

Comment: The one in the top slot will be the "site default". You can override what the CP is displaying in for a user under their user account preferences.

Comment: Perfect!  Changing my user's preferred locale solved the issue.  Thanks for the help!